# How to send global variable from one class to another class while using spring and @Transaction?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, spring-transactions

I am trying to work out a sample Spring Boot(MVC) project where i am trying to do the following in the same sequence.

1. add one customer
2. add a contact having customer id
3. add a Oppr having both customer and contact id
4. send email to the contact
5. add a ticket having opprId

The main issue here is i am trying to complete all the task under one transaction. But the method to add the ticket is in another class. While trying to add the ticket i need to send opprId to TicketAdd class. I am able to get the global variable value while i am not using @Transaction at method level but at the moment i use @Transaction in AddTicket Class for addFields method then not able to get the value of the global variable.

This Is my OpprAdd Service class.

```
package com.transaction.spring.service;

import java.util.Date;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Propagation;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.transaction.spring.model.Customer;
import com.transaction.spring.model.CustomerContact;
import com.transaction.spring.model.SalesOppr;
import com.transaction.spring.repo.ContactRepo;
import com.transaction.spring.repo.CustomerRepo;
import com.transaction.spring.repo.OpprRepo;

@Service
public class OpprAdd {
    @Autowired
    ContactRepo contactRepo;

    @Autowired
    CustomerRepo customerRepo;

    @Autowired
    OpprRepo opprRepo;

    @Autowired
    TicketAdd ticketAdd;

    public ModelAndView getModelAndView(Model model, ModelAndView modelAndView) {
        modelAndView.addObject("SalesOppr", new SalesOppr());
        modelAndView.setViewName("enquiry-add");
        return modelAndView;

    }

    public ModelAndView postModelAndView(Model model, SalesOppr SalesOppr, ModelAndView modelAndView) {

        addOppr(SalesOppr);

        modelAndView.addObject("SalesOppr", SalesOppr);
        modelAndView.setViewName("enquiry-add");
        return modelAndView;
    }

    private void sendEmailSms(SalesOppr SalesOppr) {
        System.err.println("123");
    }

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void addOppr(SalesOppr SalesOppr) {
        Customer Customer = new Customer();
        Customer.setCustomerName(SalesOppr.getCustomerName());

        customerRepo.save(Customer);

        CustomerContact CustomerContact = new CustomerContact();
        CustomerContact.setContactFname(SalesOppr.getContactFname());
        CustomerContact.setContactLname(SalesOppr.getContactLname());
        CustomerContact.setContactCustomerId(Customer.getCustomerId());

        contactRepo.save(CustomerContact);

        SalesOppr.setOpprTitle("New Oppr");
        SalesOppr.setOpprDate(new Date());
        SalesOppr.setOpprDesc("Hello");
        SalesOppr.setOpprCustomerId(Customer.getCustomerId());
        SalesOppr.setOpprContactId(CustomerContact.getContactId());
        opprRepo.save(SalesOppr);

        sendEmailSms(SalesOppr);

        ticketAdd.ticketOwner = "1";
        ticketAdd.ticketOpprId = String.valueOf(SalesOppr.getOpprId());
        ticketAdd.addFields();

    }

}
```

This is my TicketAdd Service class.In this class if i use @Transactional then i am not getting the ticketOwner and ticketOpprId value what i have set in OpprAdd class.

```
package com.transaction.spring.service;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Service
public class TicketAdd {

    public String ticketOwner = "0";
    public String ticketOpprId = "0";

    @Transactional
    public void addFields() {
        System.out.println("ticketOwner====" + ticketOwner);
        System.out.println("ticketOpprId====" + ticketOpprId);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

> @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)

Try

> @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.SUPPORTS)

Explanation:

**REQUIRES_NEW:**

Indicates that a new tx has to start every time the target method is called. If already a tx is going on, it will be suspended before starting a new one.

**SUPPORTS:**

Indicates that the target method can execute irrespective of atx. If atxis running, it will participate in the same tx. If executed without a tx it will still execute if no errors.
Methods which fetch data are the best candidates for this option.

Comment: Your explanation is correct according to the documentation and theory but my question is mostly about passing the variable value from the class a to b while both are in transaction. @Nilanjan B

Answer (score 0):

As I can see from the below code:

```
        ticketAdd.ticketOwner = "1";
        ticketAdd.ticketOpprId = String.valueOf(SalesOppr.getOpprId());
        ticketAdd.addFields();
```

That the changes made to `ticketAdd` are not saved/committed.

So, when you're reading the value in other class, then it doesn't retrieve because of default nature of `@Transactional`. So, try with the following:

```
    @Transactional(isolation=Isolation.READ_UNCOMMITTED)
    public void addFields() {
        System.out.println("ticketOwner====" + ticketOwner);
        System.out.println("ticketOpprId====" + ticketOpprId);
    }
```

I hope it works.

Comment: Thanks for your support but @Transactional(isolation=Isolation.READ_UNCOMMITTED) also not working and Its not about reading uncommitted. Suppose i am not fetching the value form the data base then the code should work fine in case of    ticketAdd.ticketOwner = "1";cause its hard coded here but this is also not working.